# Run function through all combinations of rows in R

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
                                        4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"), class = "factor"), 
                     result = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                                1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
                     weight = c(0.5, 0.8, 1, 3, 3.4, 1.6, 4, 1.6, 2.3, 2.1, 2, 
                                1, 0.1, 6, 2.3, 1.6, 1.4, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 
                                1.6, 1.8)), .Names = c("area", "result", "weight"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                        -26L))
```

I wish to calculate the risk difference between all combinations of areas (i.e. a1 and a2, a1 and a3, a2 and a3).  Preferably this would be in a matrix form.

Up till now, I have just looked at comparing the risk difference (RD) between the regions with the highest and lowest results:

```
#Include only regions with highest or lowest percentage
df.summary <- data.table(df.summary)
incl <- df.summary[c(which.min(result), which.max(result)),area]
df.new <- df[df$area %in% incl,]
df.new$area <- factor(df.new$area)

#Run relative difference
df.xtabs <- xtabs(weight ~ result + area, data=df.new)
df.xtabs

#Produce xtabs table
RD.result <- prop.test(x=df.xtabs[,2], n=rowSums(df.xtabs),  correct = FALSE)
RD <- round(- diff(RD.result$estimate), 3)
```

... But how would I change this to ensure the code runs through all combinations of areas without having to specify each one in turn? (I may have up to 19 areas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `combn` function. For example,

```
uniqueCombinations <- combn(unique(as.character(df$area)), 2)
resultDF <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=dim(uniqueCombinations)[2], ncol=2+1))#2 col for unique combination and 1 for RD value 
names(resultDF) <- c(paste0("area_", 1:2), "RD")
for(i in 1:dim(uniqueCombinations)[2]){
    #iterate over a unique combination
    incl <- uniqueCombinations[,i]
    print(incl) 
    #Your code
    df.new <- df[df$area %in% incl,]
    df.new$area <- factor(df.new$area)

    #Run relative difference
    df.xtabs <- xtabs(weight ~ result + area, data=df.new)
    df.xtabs
    df.xtabs1 <- data.frame(df.xtabs)

    #Produce xtabs table
    RD.result <- prop.test(x=df.xtabs[,2], n=rowSums(df.xtabs),  correct = FALSE)
    RD <- round(- diff(RD.result$estimate), 3)

    resultDF[i, 1:2] <- incl
    resultDF[i, 3] <- RD

}
resultDF
```

**UPDATE** : code update to create a resultDF, which will have result from loop.

Comment: Thanks @Kumar Manglam - combn looks good.  Is it possible to have all the summary data in a dataframe with all the combination options?  The df.xtabs seems to be the last combination - V6 in 'uniqueCombinations' - a3 and a4 so I presume the RD responds to this as well?

Comment: Thanks @Kumar Manglam.  Can I ask how you specify the column name 'RD' in the resultDF dataframe? In your 'produce xtabs table' command code I have added RDpvalue <- round(RD.result$"p.value", 4), and then in the 'produce xtabs table', I have added resultDF[i, 6] <- RDpvalue, but the column name in the resulting dataframe is V4 instead of RDpvalue - how can I change this?

Comment: After initializing data frame, I do `names(resultDF) <- c(paste0("area_", 1:2), "RD")` to assign names. You can add the names RDpvalue to code. But make sure that you accrodingly initialize the data frame i.e. have appropriate number of rows and columns in the data frame.